# Plot R² using corrplot()

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, r-corrplot

I am really new to R and just encountered my first problem.
I generated a correlation matrix with added significance level. However, I just realized that I need the R² value instead of R.

Is there any possibility to plot R² instead of R?

This is the code I used:

```
res <- cor(data, use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson")
round(res, 2)
library(corrplot)
corrplot(res, method = "color", addCoef.col="black", order ="original",number.cex= 12/ncol(res))
library("Hmisc")
res2 <- rcorr(as.matrix(res))
corrplot(res, method = "color", addCoef.col="black", order = "original",number.cex= 12/ncol(res), p.mat = res2$P, sig.level = 0.01)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: corrplot(res*res)    ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Easier than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Just so that the question is not unanswered...
All that you have to do is call corrplot on the square of r

```
corrplot(res*res)
```